# DAX: Merge two tables selectively (based on a value in a row)

Tags: merge, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables:

1. Table with Division and Entity within divisions
2. Table with projects identified per entity or for all entities in a division.

> ```
> **Table 1: Organization**  
> id    Division    Entity  
> - - - - - - - - - - - - -  
> 0     Europe      France   
> 1     Europe      Germany   
> 2     Europe      Italy   
> 3     Europe      Spain   
> 4     China       North   
> 5     China       East   
> 6     China       West   
> 7     China       South
> ```

> ```
> **Table 2: Project**
> id    Division    Org.            Project  
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   
> 1     Europe      France          Project 1   
> 2     Europe      Germany         Project 2   
> 3     Europe      Germany         Project 3  
> 4     Europe      All entities    Project 4   
> 5     Europe      All entities    Project 5  
> 6     China       East            Project 6   
> 7     China       All entities    Project 7
> ```

Some projects are specific to [Org.]'s, while others are relevant for all [Org.]'s in the [Division]. In these cases the value "All entities" is used.

I want to merge both tables based on [Division], but just for Plan[Org.] = "All entities", while the rows with other values (e.g. "France", "Germany") should just be repeated.

The resulting table should look like this:

> ```
> **Table 3: Merge**
> id    Division    Org.            Entity      Project  
> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   
> 1     Europe      France          France      Project 1   
> 2     Europe      Germany         Germany     Project 2   
> 3     Europe      Germany         Germany     Project 3  
> 4     Europe      All entities    France      Project 4   
> 4     Europe      All entities    Germany     Project 4   
> 4     Europe      All entities    Spain       Project 4   
> 4     Europe      All entities    Italy       Project 4   
> 5     Europe      All entities    France      Project 5  
> 5     Europe      All entities    Germany     Project 5  
> 5     Europe      All entities    Spain       Project 5  
> 5     Europe      All entities    Italy       Project 5  
> 6     China       East            East        Project 6   
> 7     China       All entities    North       Project 7  
> 7     China       All entities    East        Project 7  
> 7     China       All entities    South       Project 7  
> 7     China       All entities    West        Project 7
> ```

A physical relationship between the tables doesn't work because of the missing "All entities" value in the Organization table, but it can be added when with an additional [Entity id] column in the Project table, if needed.

I prefer DAX. Solutions in PowerQuery are less preferred as I am not so fluent in M, but still welcome if
available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these below steps in **Power Query**-

**Step-1:** Create a *custom column** in table **Organization** as below-

[image]

Here is the output-

[image]

**Step-2:** Create **2** **Duplicate** table from table **Project** and name them as - **Project_all_emtities** and **Project_others**

**Step-3:** Go to **Advanced Editor** for table **Project_all_emtities** and replace the following code-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXItLcovSAUy3IoS85JBjICi/KzU5BIFQwUFBaVYnWglI2Rl7qlFuYl5lUjqjGDqjPGrM4YqM0FW5piTo5CaV5JZkplajKTWBGamKRGKTaFqzYBizhmZeYkgPYnFJUhKzGDmmSOpwWGcuVJsLAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, Division = _t, #"Org." = _t, #"Project  " = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"Division", type text}, {"Org.", type text}, {"Project  ", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Division", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Org.", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Trimmed Text", each ([#"Org."] = "All entities")),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"Division", "Org."}, Organization, {"Division", "Custom"}, "Organization", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Organization" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Organization", {"Entity  "}, {"Organization.Entity  "}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Organization",{"id", "Division", "Org.", "Organization.Entity  ", "Project  "}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Organization.Entity  ", "Entity"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Step-4:** Go to **Advanced Editor** for table **Project_others** and replace the following code-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXItLcovSAUy3IoS85JBjICi/KzU5BIFQwUFBaVYnWglI2Rl7qlFuYl5lUjqjGDqjPGrM4YqM0FW5piTo5CaV5JZkplajKTWBGamKRGKTaFqzYBizhmZeYkgPYnFJUhKzGDmmSOpwWGcuVJsLAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, Division = _t, #"Org." = _t, #"Project  " = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"Division", type text}, {"Org.", type text}, {"Project  ", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Division", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Org.", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Trimmed Text", each [#"Org."] <> "All entities"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"Division", "Org."}, Organization, {"Division", "Entity  "}, "Organization", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Organization" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Organization", {"Entity  "}, {"Organization.Entity  "}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Organization",{"id", "Division", "Org.", "Organization.Entity  ", "Project  "}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Organization.Entity  ", "Entity"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Step-5:** Create a new table By appending **Project_all_emtities** and **Project_others** with this below code-

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({Project_all_emtities, Project_others}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Division", Order.Descending}, {"Project  ", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you mkRabbani! Can follow your solution. Will try out this solution as well. May even stick with this. Thanks!!

Comment: Hope you will find your expected output this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the name of the columns, for the table `Project`. The function `CROSSJOIN` doesn't like to have duplicate columns names. `Organization` table is the same.

**PROJECT TABLE**

```
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| id_project | Division_project |     Org.     |  Project  |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1          | Europe           | France       | Project 1 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2          | Europe           | Germany      | Project 2 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 3          | Europe           | Germany      | Project 3 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 4          | Europe           | All entities | Project 4 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 5          | Europe           | All entities | Project 5 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 6          | China            | East         | Project 6 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 7          | China            | All entities | Project 7 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

The code uses two variables `_directrel` and `_allentity`, their outputs correspond to tables. Each one of those uses a `CROSSJOIN` surrounded by a FILTER statement. The first uses a direct relationship between divisions and entities. The second variable only uses divisions as a link and filtering the `Project` only for `All Entities`.

After the `RETURN` statement, there is a `UNION` statement, that makes a union between the tables, surrounded by `SELECTCOLUMNS` to control the order of the columns.

```
Merge =
VAR _directrel =
    GROUPBY (
        FILTER (
            CROSSJOIN ( Organization, Project ),
            [Division] = [Division_project]
                && [Entity] = [Org.]
        ),
        [id_project],
        [Division],
        [Org.],
        [Entity],
        [Project]
    )
VAR _allentity =
    GROUPBY (
        FILTER (
            CROSSJOIN ( Organization, FILTER ( Project, [Org.] = "All Entities" ) ),
            [Division] = [Division_project]
        ),
        [id_project],
        [Division],
        [Org.],
        [Entity],
        [Project]
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        UNION ( _allentity, _directrel ),
        "id", [id_project],
        "Division", [Division],
        "Org.", [Org.],
        "Entity", [Entity],
        "Project", [Project]
    )
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Angelo! Also for the explanation. Big help!